# Positional arguments not allowed in elasticsearch plugin

Tags: java, elasticsearch

While installing elastic search plugin analysis-phonetic it shows this error:
I first ran elasticsearch.bat before running this command but still not working.

```
$ ./bin/elasticsearch.bat install analysis-phonetic
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Starts Elasticsearch

Option                Description
------                -----------
-E <KeyValuePair>     Configure a setting
-V, --version         Prints Elasticsearch version information and exits
-d, --daemonize       Starts Elasticsearch in the background
-h, --help            Show help
-p, --pidfile <Path>  Creates a pid file in the specified path on start
-q, --quiet           Turns off standard output/error streams logging in console
-s, --silent          Show minimal output
-v, --verbose         Show verbose output
ERROR: Positional arguments not allowed, found [install, analysis-phonetic]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right command is:

```
bin/elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-phonetic
```

See [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/installation.html).