# Java version checker error while installing elasticsearch plugin analysis-phonetic

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have elastic search in directory F:/elasticsearch-7.6.1/bin

```
$ bin/elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-phonetic
Error: Could not find or load main class org.elasticsearch.tools.java_version_checker.JavaVersionChecker
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.tools.java_version_checker.JavaVersionChecker
```

Comment: You should use the latest version available. 7.12.0. It's also hard to know how/what you exactly installed. If you are using windows, I'd suggest to install https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/windows.html

Comment: I'm confused because you were saying that it's working in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66850621/positional-arguments-not-allowed-in-elasticsearch-plugin

Comment: yes the command worked but java version checker not working